# Function to insert a tag into a database

Tags: php, sql, error-handling, php5

I'm developing a MVC structured RESTful API project **(thanks to the help of Mārtiņš Tereško for explaining it)**.

Almost all of my functions look similar to this:

```
 /**
    * Insert Tag
    */
    public function insertTag(Tag\Tag $tag)
    {   
        try{
            //Names
            $name = new Common\Name();

            //Insert into main table
            $sql = "INSERT INTO tag VALUES(null)";
            $statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
            $statement->execute();

            //Get main table id
            $tagId = $this->connection->lastInsertId();

            //Insert into audit tag table
            $sql = "INSERT INTO tag_audit(behaviour,action_peformed,state,tag_id) VALUES(:behaviour,'insert','P',:tag_id)";
            $statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
            $statement->bindValue(':behaviour',$tag->getBehaviour(),PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $statement->bindValue(':tag_id',$tagId,PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $statement->execute();

            //Insert into names
            $name->setNames($tag->getNames()[0]);
            $values = $name->getBulkValue(
                $name->getValue(),
                ["'insert'","'P'",$tagId]
            ); 

            $sql = "INSERT INTO tag_name_audit(name,language,action_peformed,state,tag) VALUES".$values;
            $statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
            $statement->execute();

            $response = ['status'=>200,'Message'=>'Successfully inserted.'];

        }catch(\Exception $e){

             $sql = "DELETE FROM tag WHERE id_tag = :id_tag";
             $statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
             $statement->bindValue(":id_tag",$tagId,PDO::PARAM_INT);
             $statement->execute();


             $sql = "DELETE FROM tag_audit WHERE tag_id = :id_tag";
             $statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
             $statement->bindValue(":id_tag",$tagId,PDO::PARAM_INT);
             $statement->execute();

             $response = ['status'=>409,'Message'=>'Error '.$e->getCode()];
        }
        $tag->setResponse($response);
    }
```

I don't like how much code there is and i tought of having some mapper helper classes which will handle at least a portion of it.But still i don't think that it's the right solution.

Also since i parse the bulk value over an array i know that it's not secure ....how could i solve that part?

So the question is how could i improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use a [transaction](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#transactions), so you won't need all the manual delete queries
- Use shorter PDO syntax.
- Log errors
- Use **prepared statements**

In the end it should be like

```
public function insertTag(Tag\Tag $tag)
{   
    try{
        //Names
        $name = new Common\Name();

        $pdo->beginTransaction();

        //Insert into main table
        $this->connection->query("INSERT INTO tag VALUES(null)");

        //Get main table id
        $tagId = $this->connection->lastInsertId();

        //Insert into audit tag table
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tag_audit(behaviour,action_peformed,state,tag_id) VALUES(?,'insert','P',?)";
        $this->connection->prepare($sql)->execute([$tag->getBehaviour(), $tagId]);

        //Insert into names
        // you should be using prepared statements here
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tag_name_audit(name,language,action_peformed,state,tag) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
        $statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
        foreach (whatever function supplies the name as $name) {
            $statement->execute([$name]);
        }
        $response = ['status'=>200,'Message'=>'Successfully inserted.'];

        $pdo->commit();
    }catch(\Exception $e){

         $pdo->rollback();
         error_log($e);
         $response = ['status'=>409,'Message'=>'Error '.$e->getCode()];
    }
    $tag->setResponse($response);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the transactions it will help me a lot!!!

Comment: Isn't bulk import better than to execute the same function several times?

Comment: Nope it's no better. Prepared statements are optimized for multiple inserts. just prepare once and then execute in the loop

Comment: Didn't know that!!I taught that bulk import is better.Thanks a lot  sir :D

Comment: I'd say both methods are good. You can use either, but given prepared statements are safer, it makes the choice obvious.